# redirect and php in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a weird issue when ugrading to a newer php version (now I have 5.5.9)

my old .htaccess tells me:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

direct.php would contain e.g.:

```
<?php 
if ($id == "") {$link = "http://www.example.com";}
if ($id == "10") {$link = "http://google.com";} 
header("Location: $link"); 
exit;
?>
```

a link like this:

```
http://www.example.com/direct.php?id=10
```

should direct me to google.com but it wont work anymore and just directs me to www.example.com again, before it worked fine.
I assume something changed in the variable passing through at php or is it just my htaccess code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems `register_globals` is the issue. http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Add following line at the top:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

add this before using $id: `$id = $_GET['id']`